# activation email with View Model in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, view, viewmodel

I have a controller to register user on site and it works correctly.(It has RegisterViewModel)

```
 public class RegisterUserViewModel
{

    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

and its register function:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterUserViewModel registerUserViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {       
            var result = await _userService.RegisterUser(registerUserViewModel);

            switch (result)
            {
                case RegisterUserResult.Error:
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "failed");

                    TempData[ErrorMessage] = "failed"
                    break;

                case RegisterUserResult.UserExist:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Registered Before");
                   break;

                case RegisterUserResult.Success:
            

           
                    ViewBag.active = x;
                    return View("SuccessRegister",registerUserViewModel);

            }
        }

        return View(registerUserViewModel);
    }
```

but for activation his email I write a function with different view model for writing clean code and get just active code from data base. it works alone too correctly

```
 public class EmailActiveAccountViewModel
{

    public string EmailActiveCode { get; set; }

}
```

and its function works correctly.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult>ActiveEmailAccount(EmailActiveAccountViewModel activeCode)
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {
            var result = await _userService.ActiveAccount(activeCode);
            ViewData["Active"] = result;

        }
        return View(activeCode);
    
}
```

I pass activecode from viewbag:

View:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <h3> @Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName dear!</h3>
    <p>successful register "@Model.Email"  </p>
    <p>
         <a href="https://localhost:44385/active?EmailActiveCode=@ViewBag.active">Activation</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

### with this way active code goes to function: ActiveEmailCode

If I set a separate link in the web , "ActiveAccount" funcation works correctly,
email send to user's email correctly but "ActiveAccount" funcation does not work. EmailActiveCode=@ViewBag.active does not come to the user's email
I set with gmail smtp and change the setting of gmail as a help links
see the pic:
if i set the link in pasge is correct:
[image]

but after send to email ,it does not work, user recive the email, but this linl does not work , becasue emailactivecode does not come to function just in email
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question a bit. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @chen I solve that problem , sorry now i have new one for activeaccount link just in email.